# Delete registry folder and sub folder using VBS

Tags: vbscript

I want to delete registry folder and sub-folder under it using vb script.

In reg file we can script like below:

```
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\abc\prr]
```

Above script will delete sub-folder under prr

How to achieve same using VB script?

I tried using **.RegDelete** but I think it work only for key and not for registry folder.

Thanks.

Comment: Regdelete. If it ends in a \ then must be a key. No \ then a value. Keys are folders.

Comment: @tony bd: Not working

Comment: What is not working - Sh.RegDelete "HKCR\.txt\" deletes a key Sh.RegDelete "HKCR\.txt\ShellNew" deletes the default value of the ShellNew key, Sh.RegDelete "HKCR\.txt\ShellNew\NullFile" deletes the value called nullfile.

Answer (score 0):

[path] RegDelete [Key] | [Value]

Path Path to RegDelete (so Windows can find it). See the tip on the Windows 98 Tips and Hacks page to make Windows always find it.

Nothing Starts RegDelete with a User Interface. Do not enclose keys or values in inverted commas when typing the key or value to delete.

Key The key to delete. Keys always end in a backslash. If the key contains a space it must be enclosed in inverted commas. Keys and sub-keys will be deleted.

Value The value to delete. Values do not have a trailing backslash. If the key contains a space it must be enclosed in inverted commas.

Copy the following lines into a new text document and save as RegDelete.vbs.

```
'RegDelete.vbs
'Deletes keys or values from the registry.
'
'
On Error Resume Next
vbPara=vbCRLF & vbCRLF
strExplain="RegDelete deletes keys and values from the registry." & vbPara & "Keys must end with a backspace and values must not." & vbPara & "Start without parameters to type in a key or value to delete, or place the key or value on the command line (use inverted commas to surround the key or value if it contains spaces)."  & vbPara & "Continue"
strTitle="Reg Delete"
Key=""
Dim silent
Silent=""

Dim Sh
Set Sh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ReportErrors "Creating Shell"

Key=GetKey()
If Key<>"" then 
    B=Sh.RegRead (Key)
    If Err.Number=0 Then 
        Sh.RegDelete Key
        If Err.Number =0 Then 
            If silent<>"yes" Then MsgBox Key & " deleted", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, strTitle
        Else
            ReportErrors "DeletingKey"
        End If
    Else
        If Err.Number=-2147024893 then 
            Err.Clear
            MsgBox Key & " didn't exist", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, strTitle
        Else
            ReportErrors "Reading before Deleting Key"
        End If
    End If
End If

ReportErrors "Main"

Function GetKey()
    Dim Ag
    Set Ag=Wscript.Arguments
    ReportErrors "Creating Aguments"
    If Ag.Count=1 then GetKey=Ag(0)
    Silent="yes"
    If Ag.Count >1 then sgBox "Too many parameters on command line. Try enclosing the key in a space",vbOKOnly + vbCritical, strTitle

    If Ag.Count=0 then 
        If MsgBox (strExplain, vbYesNo + vbInformation, strTitle)=6 Then
            GetKey=InputBox ("Enter the value or key to delete." & vbPara & "Keys must end in a backspace.", strTitle, strNamet1)
        End If
    End If
End Function

Sub ReportErrors(strModuleName)
    If err.number<>0 then Msgbox "Error occured in " & strModuleName & " module of " & err.number& " - " & err.description & " type" , vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Something unexpected"
    Err.clear
End Sub
```